# How to determine the last activ UITextField in Xcode

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I am new to swift and i am playing around with a little converter app. I Have two TextFields and one "convert" button.
I want to overwrite the non acticv Textfield with the converted value from the last activ TextField.
I know it would be easier with more Textfields and more buttons but i would like to solve it this way.

Can anybody give me an advise?

```
var NumberC = Int(InputCelcius.text!)!
var NumberF = Int(InputFahrenheit.text!)!

if InputCelcius.isFirstResponder {
    if (InputCelcius.text?.isEmpty)! {
        NumberC=0
        print("NumberC is empty")
    }
    NumberC = NumberC * 9/5 + 32
    InputFahrenheit.text = " \(NumberC)"
}

else if InputFahrenheit.isFirstResponder {  
    if (InputFahrenheit.text?.isEmpty)! {
        NumberF=0
        print("NumberF is empty")     
    }
    NumberF = (NumberF - 32) * 5/9
    InputCelcius.text = " \(NumberF)"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d suggest using the `UITextFieldDelegate` function `textFieldDidEndEditing`. Make sure you subclass your viewController as a `UITextFieldDelegate`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

Set each textField's delegate to self in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    InputFahrenheit.delegate = self
    InputCelsius.delegate = self
}
```

With this method you wouldn't even need a UIButton, but you could use the button to force the textField to end editing like this.

```
@objc func buttonAction (sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Which will call this delegate method if the user was editing a textField.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing (textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.isEmpty {return} //this prevents nil errors and user would have to type in "0" if wishing to convert zero.
    if textField == InputCelsius {
        let conversion = Float(textField.text!) * 9/5 + 32
        InputFahrenheit.text = String(format: “%.f”, conversion) //“%.1f” will show one decimal place and so forth
    } else if textField == InputFahrenheit {
        let conversion = ( Float(textField.text!) - 32 ) * 5/9
        InputCelsius.text = String(format: “%.f”, conversion)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed assitance. It works great and I learned a lot. Thanks.

Comment: note* as your code becomes more complex, maybe with more UITextFields you may need to change the `if.textField.isEmpty {return}` line. @Winz

Comment: Two other things that came to my attention: why can´t i use `textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)` ?

Comment: @Winz you can but i don't see how you could make a conversion before the user enters a value since textFieldDidBeginEditing is called when user first taps on UITextField.

Comment: And why gives just an "-" character without numbers an error?

Comment: @Winz "_" do you mean in the function parameters? if so no this isn't an error. It's standard syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I‘m not quite sure about that but I think if you press the button, the button itself will become first responder, so your code won‘t work.

The proper way to do that, would be to set IBAction functions that get called when you finish editing one of your textfields. Just connect the Textfields inside your storyboard to the code like you did it with your button.

Then you can set up two functions, one for each of the textfields, so you don‘t have to worry about firstresponder.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you also have an idea how i can check, if the textfield is empty? `if (InputFahrenheit.text?.isEmpty)! ` seems to be the wrong way.

Comment: No, that's actually the right way. You could also do if `InputFahrenheit.text.isEmpty! == ""`. Obviously this will only work if you `InputFahrenheit.text` isn't `nil`.